# What is the fastest way to check for the presence of many FK values in a large table?

Tags: postgresql, performance, subquery

I have 2 tables, approximately this:

```
Parent_table: Parent_id bigint, Loc geometry
Child_table: Child_id bigint, 
             parent_id bigint, 
             record_date timestamp, 
             value double precision, 
             category character varying(10)
```

I need to query subsets of child table for varying conditions (location, date range, value range, category). As part of this, I winnow down the locations from the parent table and then want to get all the matching records

The obvious way to do this is:

```
with limited_parents as
(
 select parent_id from parent_table where [location condition]
)
select [ columns ] from child_table where parent_id in 
         (select parent_id from limited_parents)
and [ other conditions for record_date, value, category ]
```

`Child_table` has >200m records, partioned by year. It has an index of the parent_key and the other columns are all included in an index, in that order.

`Parent_table` has <10k records. Each Parent could easily have > 1m+ child records (the numbers of child records per parent are widely distributed from a few hundred to million+). The set of parents which are in scope in any query (and therefore included in that sub-select) might be from 1 to several hundred.

Database is currently Postgres 10.

The query is performant for ranges of a couple of years/partitions, but gets significantly slower as the amount of date in scope in increases.

I have freedom to adjust indexes and change the queries. Is there a more efficient way of doing this query?  *(Flattening the two tables, and putting the location on the child table and doing the geo intersection there, makes the whole thing orders of magnitude slower)*

Answer (score 0):

Your query is written in a complicated and inefficient fashion. In particular, CTEs are an optimizer fence in older PostgreSQL versions.

Try this:

```
SELECT [ columns ] FROM child_table AS c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM parent_table AS p
              WHERE [location condition on p]
                AND p.parent_id = c.parent_id)
  AND [ other conditions for record_date, value, category ]
```

Create an index on the foreign key column of the large table to speed up a nested loop join. Set `work_mem` high to speed up a hash join. PostgreSQL will autonatically pick the best solution.

Comment: I've done both of those. I'm looking to see if there's a better way to structure the query to reduce the work or improve index usage.

On the "automatically pick the best solution" that definitely not always the case - in one of the iterations of the full version of this code, I'd managed to structure it so that it did parallel searches and gathers which were very fast; I upgraded to pg11 and it started using index scans instead (as all the keys were present in an index), which is theoretically a good idea, but was actually 10-100x slower than the parallel version.

Comment: I have added a more efficient version of your query.